# Spec passing no matter what I type in "text:"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This is the spec:

```
  describe "visit tag list page" do

    before do 
      sign_in user
      visit tag_list_path
    end

    it { page.body.should have_selector('.tag_list li a', text: post.tags.sample.name) }
    it { should have_selector('.tag_list li',             text: "(1)") }
  end
```

I tried changing this part:

```
    it { should have_selector('.tag_list li',             text: "(0)") }
```

To check my test. To my surprise the test passed. And it shouldn't:

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Here is the HTML output:

[image]

Comment: I am wondering that which kind of 'test fixtures' you are using? and which kind of front-end libraries you are using?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap. Sorry what are 'test fixtures'?

Comment: Are you using webrat or capybara ?

Comment: @Frederick Cheung capybara

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to confirm that you are actually logged in, use [save_and_open_page](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara#Debugging) method. Can also use it to confirm that what the test sees is what you were actually expecting. Quite commonly, you were missing something.

You will also need the `launchy` gem for this.